# How check is my file create/modyfy after other file?

Tags: ruby, file

I need a function similar 'make' program.

If my file not exist or if file need update (modyfy time is before my other file) tell me true.

I have one file dependencies to other file. How update it only if neccesary.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use [`FileUtils.uptodate?`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-uptodate-3F).

> ```
> uptodate?(new, old_list)`
> ```
>
> Returns `true` if `new` is newer than all `old_list`. Non-existent files are older than any file.

In your example you can use it like this:

```
unless FileUtils.uptodate?('file_a', ['file_b'])
  # file_a needs to be updated
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'time_difference'

TimeDifference.between(File.ctime("FilenameA"), File.ctime("FilenameB.txt")).humanize
```

Using gem 'time_difference'

trouble with other lang than english (withouth .humanize You get number)